# How to use MSBuild for Visual Studio 2008 in a docker container?

Tags: docker, visual-studio-2008, msbuild

I want to create a docker container that can build solutions using MSBuild for Visual Studio 2008. I have already installed the .NET Framework 3.5 and .NET 3.5 SP1 on the image. However, when I try to build using MSBuild.exe, I get an error:

> error MSB3411: Could not load the Visual C++ component "VCBuild.exe".
> If the component is not installed, either 1) install the Microsoft
> Windows SDK for Windows Server 2008 and .NET Framework 3.5, or 2)
> install Microsoft Visual Studio 2008

This error seems straighthood, and suggests that I should install either the SDK or VS2008. However, I cannot find a downloadable installer for either of these today. So my question is, has anyone found a way to download the Microsoft Windows SDK for Windows Server 2008 and .NET Framework 3.5 and silently install it?

Alternatively, I do have the full version of Visual Studio 2008 installed on another pc. Is it possible to manually copy only the files that are required for VCBuild.exe to the docker image?

Comment: Do you have an MSDN subscription or [Visual Studio Dev Essentials](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/dev-essentials/)? With Dev Essentials you can download a VS2008 trial from [https://my.visualstudio.com/Downloads?q=visual%20studio%202008](https://my.visualstudio.com/Downloads?q=visual%20studio%202008)

Comment: Unfortunately a trial version would not be useful

Comment: Are you using the free community edition of Visual Studio? Or do you have a Visual Studio Professional or Enterprise subscription?  The subscription includes licenses for older versions.